# Please Help Me Intepret This Code SWIFT

Tags: swift

```
display.text = newValue != nil ? "\(newValue!)" : " "
```

Does the syntax of the code mean, let display.text = newValue, if it does not equal nil let it be an optional of newValue as a string or " ". This interpretation is a guess, any help that can be provided will be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Its a ternary operator. It is use for some condition. If condition is true then it execute the part after `?` otherwise the part after `:`. In your case the condition is if newValue not equals to `nil` then unwrap it otherwise return empty string.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation

> **Ternary Conditional Operator**
>
> The ternary conditional operator is a special operator with three
>   parts, which takes the form `question ? answer1 : answer2`. It is a
>   shortcut for evaluating one of two expressions based on whether
>   question is true or false. If question is true, it evaluates `answer1`
>   and returns its value; otherwise, it evaluates `answer2` and returns its
>   value.
>
> The ternary conditional operator is shorthand for the code below:
>
> ```
> if question {
>    answer1 
> } else {
>    answer2
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

it means that

```
if newValue == nil {
    display.text = " "
} else {
    display.text = "(newValue!)"
}
```

if newValue is not nil, display.text will be (newValue!).

if you want to show newValue's value,

you should write that

```
if newValue == nil {
    display.text = " "
} else {
    display.text = "\(newValue!)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers about the ternary operator are correct.

An alternative way to write this would be with the "nil-coalescing operator" `??`:

```
display.text = newValue ?? ""
```

Which means if the value before ?? Is not nil, use that unwrapped value, else use the value after ??